# Get User Login Data (date, time... )

Tags: functions, database, hooks, login

I did my best looking for information about this subject. Your guidance is appreciated.

My goal is to perform some actions based on the number of user logins on my website per month and login days consecutivity.

How can I get a specific user Login Data (date, time... ) using wordpress functions?

If not what are the tables and fields to adress using  SQL queries to get such infromation  from database?

Or I should maybe create and  manage my own user meta data using hooks on `wp_login` action?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want the user's last login information, or all logins ever, or something in between?  If the first, there's this -- http://wpmu.org/daily-tip-display-the-last-login-for-wordpress-users/

Comment: History of user logins is not natively recorded by WordPress.

Comment: check out [simple login log plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-login-log/)

Comment: thank you @Rarst for your information. While I was looking on internet before asking this question, I was feeling Wordpress doesnt record all user login history. Since I can get the last login information, I think I can count number of login days and check if the days of login were consecutive. thank you very much.